# fetchLimit returning first items instead of last

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController to fetch data from the DB and displaying in a UITableView(elements are sorted based on timestamp). Now I want to load only last 20 items using the fetchLimit property, But `fetchLimit` is returning first 20 objects instead of last.
Below is the code I have used:

```
lazy var messagesFetchController:NSFetchedResultsController<Message>? = {
        let messagesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: Constants.kTimeStampKey, ascending: true)
        messagesFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        messagesFetchRequest.fetchLimit = 5

        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: messagesFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataContentManager.managedObjectContext(), sectionNameKeyPath: "dateStamp", cacheName: nil)
        frc.delegate = self
        frc.fetchRequest.shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects = true

        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        }
        catch {
            print("Unable to fetch cart Objects")
        }
        return frc
    }()
```

Comment: You can reverse your array and then fetch the data.

Comment: set ascending: true to ascending: false and try again

Comment: but it would change ordering to reverse with decreasing timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to use `.fetchOffset`

The general process:

- format your query
- get the *total* number of records that match the query
- set `.fetchLimit = 5`
- set `.fetchOffset = totalRecords - 5`
- perform the fetch

Comment: When I try to set `fetchOffset ` it is taking lot of time to load.

Comment: In addition to the above thing I had to set batchSize to load it faster. Thanks a lot for the answer. It should be upvoted.